# How should I build using Installshield 2012 and TFS2010 / MSBuild?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, installshield

I've got a solution to build an installer with InstallShield. The solution worked local. Now I've checked it in to the version control of our TFS2010 and I want to build the InstallShield-solution after all other solutions have been built.
What is the best way to build this solution?

1. Integrate this solution into the normal build as one of the many solutions and build it as the last one? How can I set special folders (pathvariables) I defined in the InstallShield-solution (PATH_TO_APP1, PATH_TO_APP2) to look for all the assemblies to put together in the setup?
2. Or, is it better to extend the build definition by an command-line call of MSBuild.exe with the InstallShield-solution after all the other solution have been built? But how do I set the path variables calling MSBuild.exe? Is every path variable a MSBuild-property and I set it via /p:PATH_TO_APP1="xxx"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up the InstallShieldPathVariableOverrides itemgroup, or if you're not using the standard .isproj support, pass your own itemgroup into the [InstallShield task's PathVariables property](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield18helplib/msbuild.htm).

[Aidan Ryan shows](http://ajryan.tumblr.com/post/194938456/overriding-installshield-path-variables-with-msbuild) how to do the former, which looks like this. I believe his comment about needing to override the whole tree is no longer necessary in IS2012.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <InstallShieldPathVariableOverrides
      Include="((location))">
    <PathVariable>((PATH_VARIABLE_NAME))</PathVariable>
  </InstallShieldPathVariableOverrides>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: And doing this I have to verify the configuration chosen for the BuildServer ... so that the overides are only performed, if the project is build on the server and not locally?

Comment: Probably; that depends on how these are set up. Of course you could make your location depend on a property, or only add to the item group if a certain condition is met (which you could invoke by specifying another property).